With 2 linear equation with 3 variables, is there a way to prove that there a infinite whole number solutions?
If all coefficients are integers and the 2 equations are linear and consistent, then prove that there are infinite whole number solutions for all 3 variables.

By "infinite whole number solutions for all 3 variables." you mean that you have infinite solution triplets (x,y,z) where each of x,y and z is a whole number ?

Yes. I mean that there will be infinite whole number solutions for triplets (x,y,z).

Let $a_1x+b_1y+c_1z=d_1$ and $a_2x+b_2y+c_2z=d_2$ be the consistent system (always has a solution) of two equations where all coefficients are integers. If any of $a_1=0$ or $a_2=0$, you are done. So assume $a_1 \neq 0 $ and $ a_2 \neq 0$. Now multiply $1^{st}$ $eq^{n}$ with $a_2$ and $2^{nd}$ with $a_1$ on both sides.
\begin{align}
    a_1a_2x + b_1a_2y+c_1a_2z &= d_1a_2  \\
    a_2a_1x + b_2a_1y+c_2a_1z &= d_2a_1
\end{align}
Subtracting them both, you get
\begin{equation}
(b_1a_2-b_2a_1)y + (c_1a_2-c_2a_1)z = d_1a_2-d_2a_1
\end{equation}
Now you know that the above equation has infinite number of solutions. So, the system also has infinite number of solutions.
Hope this helps you.

The statement itself is not necessarily true.
For example, consider the system of equations $2x + 4y + 6z = 3$ and $4x + 10y + 8z = 5$. This system is consistent in $\mathbb{R}^3$, as the normal vectors to both planes are not parallel. However, it does not have any integer solutions because the left-hand side (LHS) of each equation is always even, while the right-hand side (RHS) is odd, making it impossible for both sides to be equal for any integer values of $x$, $y$ and $z$.
For more clarity, read about Diophantine equations (in three variables to be more specific).

Wow. Thanks for the clarification.

Clarification requested: If I understand your argument, your argument would apply even if the 2nd equation was changed (for example) to $~4x + 10y + 8z = 40,~$ because the odd/even parity argument still applies to the 1st equation, which is sufficient to prevent there being a $~\Bbb{Z^{3}}~$ solution.  Have I interpreted your argument correctly?

Yes. That's right @user2661923. That would work as well
